# kube fleged imagePullSecrets not working(ImagePullBackOff)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure

```yaml
apiVersion: kubefledged.io/v1alpha2
kind: ImageCache
metadata:
  name: imagecache1
  namespace: kube-fledged
  labels:
    app: kubefledged
    component: imagecache
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
  cacheSpec:
  - images:
    - exampleregdev.azurecr.io/vm-images/sample-img-1:0.0.1
    - exampleregdev.azurecr.io/vm-images/sample-img-2:0.0.3
    - exampleregdev.azurecr.io/vm-images/sample-img-3:0.0.1
```

I am using aregred secret to pull images from a private registry. But I get an image ImagePullBackOff error. I have my regred in the kube-fledged namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are several debugging tasks you should perform
check if you saved the pull secret correctly

```
kubectl get secrets -n kube-fledged regcred
```

if the type is `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` it's okay
after that, try to decode the secret and use it on your own machine to see if it pulls the image.

let us know if it helped you or you need further assistant :)